# How can I transform origin when I am in Edit Mode with shortcut?

Tags: transforms, origin

I come from Maya, and my first problem as you probably know is how can I transform origin in edit mode with shortcuts. Is there some good addon even paid or can I keymap this. What I want is this:

1. Select object in object mode with mouse
2. Swith to Edit mode with Tab key
3. Select some verticies with mouse and Shift key
4. Press (Some key) to switch on/off for transforming origin
5. Press (Some key) to activate on/off Snapping mode
6. Press (Some key) to switch Snapping mode, etc: edge / vertex or even closest or middle

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

here are some thing to get you started.

Shift + Tab for switching Snapping on/off
Shift + Ctrl + Tab for switching between Snapping options/methods

Transforming origin -  So you are asking for transforming origins, probably so that you can move/scale/rotate at that origin. But Blender has a more elaborate method to do so, by using 3d Cursor. Its a just a null pointer made for this purpose. Simply being in edit mode press Shift + S and you will find options to change the 3d Cursor location like this -
[image]

Also you can select some loops and snap the 3d Cursor using same method Shit+S. Still only the Cursor position will change, else nothing is going to change. Now press "." near right Shift on keyboard for this menu and you will have to select 3d Cursor , now things will move/scale/rotate from this point/3D cursor/Temporary origin. -
[image]
Also please enable Pie menu from the preferences -  ITS A GREAT TIME SAVER !

Comment: I think it would be good to edit these into one answer.. then I would know which one to UV :)

Answer (score 0):

**If you mean object origins:** (as opposed to current transfrom pivot point)

I do it by having the shipped add-on 'Pie Menus' activated, in particular, 'Origins Pie'.

It's supposed to have the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> but for some reason, (can someone suggest maybe why?) on my Linux, this won't bind, so I've switched it to <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> in my keymap, which works in Edit Mode, and Object Mode. That menu gives you most of the snapping options you will need.

You could also assign a shortcut to the Object Mode *Header > Options > Origins* checkbox, which will display the Object space axes of the selected objects, and allow them to be transformed and snapped like any other object.

Answer (score 0):

Alternately - To select options for 3d cursor
[image]

and to select the origin as 3d Cursor(Will enable blender to use 3d cursor location as origin)

[image]